# How do you find where request.host is defined in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to put `request.host` into a module but it doesn't recognize the function call.  How do I find out where `request.host` comes from so I can tack on the class?

Util.rb:

```
module Util
  extend self

  def host
    request.host
  end
end
```

Running `request.host` in my application.html view works fine.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to define a helper? Helper modules have access to the request object.

Answer (score 0):

`request.host` is passed by the 'middleware' layers (typically rack) down to the controllers, views, and helper modules.  You can't expect to access it from any other point in your code, unless you pass it in from one of these.